# How can I add digital signature to PDF online using php from epass 2003 pendrive

Tags: php, digital-signature, digital

I have Epass 2003 token pendrive. I want to use it to sign a pdf document.

Can anyone please suggest to me any website or link where I’ll sign my pdf document?

Comment: This article may be of help https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/php/DigitalSignaturesTest

Comment: Please check if this answer is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/58332133/9659885

Comment: Well, after re reading your question, if you are just looking to sign pdf online, https://web.signer.digital/